# Understanding variance in batch normalization

Tags: neural-network, normalization, conv-neural-network

I am implementing batch normalization in a deep convolutional neural network according to this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167

Normalization is performed using the following equation:

[image]

Where I have chosen epsilon to be 1e-3 for numeric stability and all variances are initialized to 1.0, all means are initialized to 0.0, and mean and variance are adjusted over time using exponential moving average.

To help me understand how my network is training, I am graphing the histograms representing the distributions of output variance coming out of each pre-activation:

[image]

What I've observed is that by the end of the first few training steps, the variance gets "slammed" down to near zero, and over the course of training, the variance stays very low for higher layers, and increases to very large values for layers near the output. Note that sqrt(1e-3) ~= 0.03 showing that
the first layer still has effectively near-zero variance.

I'm having trouble understanding what all of this means. Is this expected behavior for batch normalization or does something not seem right?